# Modify Apache Tika source code and test

Tags: java, apache-tika

I have been using Apache Tika for extracting text from different document formats. Now i want to make it handle header, footer and text boxes differently. So i downloaded source code of Tika from GitHub and trying to make changes in it

**My question:** Once i make the required changes in the source, how do i make sure that the changes i have made are not actually putting bugs in code. i mean is their any automatic test case that i can run to confirm that the code i have added doesn't effect original code in bad way?

Secondly, how can i make a jar out of the modified code and use it some where else?

Comment: What's wrong with using the normal unit tests provided by the project, as run through either Maven or Eclipse?

Comment: nothing wrong with it. I just dont know its purpose and how to run it? thsi is very basic i guess but i am new to this stuf

Comment: Same way you would any other maven-built project! It's `mvn test` for the main unit test suite. If you're new to all this, you probably want to read some maven tutorials first, but that's out-of-scope from here

Comment: ok thanks...i will look into that

Comment: Hi Gagravarr, now that i have imported Tika source code into eclipse.. i want to pass a file as input and debug the execution..how can i do that?

Comment: any progress on this?